# Phaser button drawn but click event not triggering

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So here's the set up. For some context I'm running this in Vue.js.

```
      preload () {
        this.load.image("button", button)
      },
      create () {
        this.game.stage.backgroundColor = "#ffa500";

        var button = this.game.add.button(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'button', test, this, 0);
        button.anchor.set(0.5)

        var test = function() {
          console.log('hi')
        }
      },
      update () {
      }
```

When I click on the image nothing happens. Not sure where to go on from here.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has hoisting, so the declaration of `test` will be moved to the top, but it doesn't mean the assignment will also. So your code basically runs

```
var button = undefined;
var test = undefined;// hoisted
button = this.game.add.button(this.game.world.centerX, 
this.game.world.centerY, 'button', undefined, this, 0);
button.anchor.set(0.5)
test = function() {
    console.log('hi')
}
```

If you want `test` to have a value, move the assignment of test above button, or use an inner function

```
create() {
    function test() {}
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work. I've even tried replacing the test with an anonymous function but there's still no output :\

Comment: thanks for following up, but I've switched over to pixi.js. I've already got the click working lol. I'll give you an upvote anyhow.